# Plotly graph not dipsplaying data properly in some datagroups

Tags: python, graph, plotly-python

this is my first time posting here so pleas bare with me.

I used a plotly graph to display some data I predicted with a neural network. The data we are using comes from a CSV file; we only use two variables: the date and the total number of deaths.
All the values in the CSV have the same form, and nothing stands out as seen in the following picture: [An example of the used data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dfska.png)

With most of the data groups, the graph properly displays the data: [Example of Austria](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x5ep.png)
But some data groups it does not properly displays it: [Example of Albania](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOKqE.png)

This is de code we used for the plot:

```
death_train = death_train.reshape((-1))
death_test = death_test.reshape((-1))
prediction = prediction.reshape((-1))

trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x = date_train,
    y = death_train,
    mode = "lines",
    name = "Data"
)
trace2 = go.Scatter(
    x = date_test,
    y = prediction,
    mode = "lines",
    name = "Prediction"
)
trace3 = go.Scatter(
    x = date_test,
    y = death_test,
    mode="lines",
    name = "Ground Truth"
)
layout = go.Layout(
    title = "Google Stock",
    xaxis = {'title' : "Date"},
    yaxis = {'title' : "Close"}
)
fig = go.Figure(data=[trace1, trace2, trace3], layout=layout)
fig.show()
```

Is there anybody who knows why this is occurring, and or if they know the problem lies elsewhere?
thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: The phenomenon in the Albania image is probably caused by the fact that the time series data is a string, so make sure that the time series data is in date format.

Comment: I just checked to be sure, and the both apear to be the same datatype: dtype: datetime64[ns]